# Are the following statements true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be the set of vectors $\left\{ \left( 3,1,0\right), \left( -1,0,0\right) \right\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Let $T$ be the set of vectors which are orthogonal to some vectors in $S$, and $U$ be the set of vectors which are orthogonal to all vectors in $S$. Which are true or false ?

(a) $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

(b) $T$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

(c) $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

(d) $T$ is spanning set for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

I understand the definitions of spanning, orthogonal and subspace, but I am having difficulty applying it to these True or False questions.

Answer (score 2):

For (a): does $S$ contain $(0,0,0)$? All subspaces must contain this vector.

For (b): Note that $(1,-3,1)$ and $(0,3,0)$ are both elements of $T$. Is their sum $(1,0,1)\in T$?

For (c): Clearly, $(0,0,0)\in U$. Suppose $(a,b,c),(x,y,z)\in U$. Then,

$$
(a+x,b+y,c+z)\cdot (3,1,0)=(a,b,c)\cdot(3,1,0)+(x,y,z)\cdot(3,1,0)=0+0=0.
$$ 
Similarly, $(a+x,b+y,c+z)\cdot(-1,0,0)=0$. Thus, $(a,b,c)+(x,y,z)$. See if you can show that $\lambda(a,b,c)\in U$ for all $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ as well.

For (d): Note that $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}\subset T$. What does this tell you?

Comment: The set S does not contain the zero vector, but surely we can make zero from a linear combination of the vectors in S meaning that it is apart of SpanS ?

Comment: In your question, you said that $S=\{(3,1,0),(-1,0,0)\}$. Therefore, $S$ does not contain the zero vector. span $S$ is a different set altogether.

Comment: For (d) will it span $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, since surely there will not be enough elements to span the whole of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ ?

Comment: Yes. The vectors I mentioned for a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$